# NodeJS not resolving index.ts files automatically

Tags: node.js, typescript

When I use `require` in my NodeJS + Typescript app I must add `index.ts` file to the url otherwise I get en error `Cannot find module './api'`, e.g.

`const api = require('./api/index.ts')` - works

`const api = require('./api')` - not working

My `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.5",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.1.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.32",
    "tslint": "^5.16.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript source files must be compiled to JavaScript files, before to be executed by Node.js.

For example with: `npx tsc`.

Answer (score 1):

`require` is not the default importing format when you are using `typescript` so might not resolve sometimes, try using `import * as api from './api'` instead

Answer (score 0):

This could be the result of a few things. Your package.json has little bearing on how TypeScript resolves relative imports/requires.

Check your `target`, `module` and `moduleResolution` compiler options in your `tsconfig.json` file. More specifically, `module` should be set to `"commonjs"` (for Node.js applications) and `moduleResolution` should be set to `"node"`

Read more about it **[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

indeed there were 2 issues:

- using ES5 syntax
- not compiling TS files

So instead of using `require` I've changed everything to `import` and also needed to add `ts-node` to my script, like : `nodemon --watch '*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' server.ts`